# Which Hitman games feature manual save?

Tags: pc, hitman-series

[Hitman: Codename 47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman:_Codename_47) and [Hitman: Absolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman:_Absolution) don't, only checkpoints. I am specifically asking about the PC releases (games' console counterparts often have manual saving removed).
Games considered as part of the main [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitman_(series)#Games):

- Hitman: Codename 47
- Hitman 2: Silent Assassin
- Hitman: Contracts
- Hitman: Blood Money
- Hitman: Absolution
- Hitman (2016)

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. This is a set list of Hitman games, and it's only asking about a feature within these games (manual save). It's just the same as asking "which Hitman games have x weapon?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Google searches and interpreting forum posts on the Steam forums and the official Hitman forums:

- Codename 47 has a level-based checkpoint system: if you die, you need to restart the level.
- Silent Assassin has a restricted save system: you can only save a limited amount of times per level, based on the difficulty: 7 on normal, 3 on expert and 0 on professional.
- Contracts uses a similar system as as Silent Assassin. Note that there may be a bug on more modern systems where the game sometimes fails to properly save your game. A workaround that seems to work is to make your first save on normal difficulty. All saves after that work properly.
- Blood Money has the same save system as Silent Assassin and Contracts.
- Absolution has a checkpoint based system that autosaves based on your progress.
- Hitman (2016) allows you to save freely.